# To prove SKK and II are beta equivalent, lambda calculus

Tags: functional-programming, lambda-calculus, proof-of-correctness, k-combinator, s-combinator

I am new to lambda calculus and struggling to prove the following.

SKK and II are beta equivalent.

where

S = lambda xyz.xz(yz)
K = lambda xy.x 
I = lambda x.x

I tried to beta reduce SKK by opening it up, but got nowhere, it becomes to messy. Dont think SKK can be reduced further without expanding S, K.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  SKK
= (λxyz.xz(yz))KK
→ λz.Kz(Kz)        (in two steps actually, for the two parameters)

  Kz
= (λxy.x)z
→ λy.z

  λz.Kz(Kz)
→ λz.(λy.z)(λy.z)  (again, several steps)
→ λz.z
= I
```

(You should be able to prove that `II → I`)

Answer (score 3):

;another approach with fewer steps, first reduce SK to λyz.z;

```
SKK
= (λxyz.xz(yz))KK
→ λyz.Kz(yz) K
→ λyz.(λxy.x)z(yz) K
→ λyz.(λy.z)(yz) K
→ λyz.z K
→ λz.z
= I
```