# S combinator in Erlang

Tags: lambda, erlang, lambda-calculus, s-combinator

I'm starting to learn lambda calculus and I need to implement I, S, K combinators in Erlang.
Of course, S, K, I stands for:

> S = λxyz.xz(yz) K = λxy.x I = λx.x

I have no problem understanding I=SKK transformation on paper (like presented here: [To prove SKK and II are beta equivalent, lambda calculus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785067/to-prove-skk-and-ii-are-beta-equivalent-lambda-calculus)) but it seems that I don't understand it when it comes to functional languages and high-order functions...

I managed to do I and K (lets say in module `test`):

```
i(X) -> X.
k(X) -> fun(Y) -> X end.
```

Also I know how to run K x (K x)   (SKK x = K x (K x))

```
kxk(X) -> (k(X))(k(X)).
```

But I can't get it around to write S combinator. I tried:

```
s(X) -> fun (Y) -> fun(Z) -> X,Z (Y,Z) end end.
```

But still, I'm not able to transform SKK x into x

I try to run it like this:

```
skkx(X) ->  s((k((k(X))))).
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I'm completely lost.

Comment: Indeed, your problem is purely notational. If you understand how beta-reduction works, then surely you understand the idea. The rest is just notation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Erlang shell:

```
1> I = fun (X) -> X end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.80247286>
2> K = fun (X) -> fun (Y) -> X end end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.80247286>
3> S = fun (X) -> fun (Y) -> fun (Z) -> (X(Z))(Y(Z)) end end end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.80247286>
4> ((S(K))(K))(42).
42
```

Or as functions in a module:

```
i(X) -> X.
k(X) -> fun(Y) -> X end.
s(X) -> fun (Y) -> fun (Z) -> (X(Z))(Y(Z)) end end.
```

Comment: ok, I still seems to have some problems :/
In my module I have:
i(X) -> X.
k(X) -> fun(Y) -> X end.
s(X) -> fun (Y) -> fun (Z) -> (X(Z))(Y(Z)) end end.
skk(X) ->((s(k))(k))(X).

When I run (tppr is module name):
`tppr:skk(x).`
I get:
`** exception error: bad function k
     in function  tppr:'-s/1-fun-0-'/3`

What am I missing?

Comment: In your definition of skk(X) ->((s(k))(k))(X) you have written lowercase k - this is the atom 'k', not the function k/1. If you instead write skk(X) ->((s(fun k/1))(fun k/1))(X), it should work.

Comment: Thank You, yes, that was the case, quite silly one, I must admit ;)